# Convert DER key (with pass phrase) to PEM with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, pem, backticks, der

I use this openssl command to convert a key file to pem:

`openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in LAN7008173R5.key -passin pass:12345678a -out converted_key.pem`

And when i use `cat converted_key.pem` I get this (expected result):

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQCC+8KIIUMVVphf
...
kEGx50X8z7yLGNYY34YDPIU=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

I'm trying to use backtick to run this command to save the private key value to a string to then save it to a file:

`file` = `File.read(Rails.root.join('lib', 'cer', '2', 'LAN7008173R5.key'))`

`pem_key` = `openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in #{file} -passin pass:12345678a`

But I get this error (even though is the same file and route):
ArgumentError: string contains null byte

Also when I do this:

`OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(Rails.root.join('lib', 'cer', '2', 'LAN7008173R5.key')), '12345678a')`

I get this:
OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError: Neither PUB key nor PRIV key: nested asn1 error

I also tried this:

`file` = `File.read(Rails.root.join('lib', 'cer', '2', 'LAN7008173R5.key'))`

`key` = `OpenSSL::PKey.read(file, '12345678a')`

And got this: 
ArgumentError: Could not parse PKey: no start line

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it (didnt need 'read')!

`file = Rails.root.join('lib', 'cer', '2', 'LAN7008173R5.key')`

`pem_key = openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in #{file} -passin pass:12345678a`

And got my expected result:

"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQCC+8KIIUMVVphf\nvF1VGG...
L80yqP3p6nXBohs45XsbF1\nkEGx50X8z7yLGNYY34YDPIU=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"